Vertical spacing issues with new environments in Beamer
I am having some serious trouble with vertical spacing around new environments in Beamer. Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass[beaver,8pt,compress,notheorems,usepdftitle=false]{beamer}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\newcommand\hmmax{0}
\newcommand\bmmax{0}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,mathrsfs} % Basic MATH packages.

% PARSKIP

\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

% BOXES DEFINITIONS

\makeatletter

\newtheoremstyle{style4}{10pt}{0pt}{\parskip0pt}{}{\scshape}{}{ }{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2} --- \thmnote{#3}.}
\theoremstyle{style4}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[]

\makeatother

% DOCUMENT

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Whatever 1}
Some random text.

Some more random text.
\begin{definition}[Whatever 1]
    A function $f:X\to Y$ if the moon is pink.
\end{definition}

Let $F_w=\{f\in Y^X\mid f\text{ satisfies Whatever 1}\}$.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Whatever2}
Some random text.

Some more random text.
\begin{definition}[Whatever 2]
    A function $f:X\to Y$ satisfies Whatever 2 if the next equation is satisfied:
\begin{gather}
    f(x)=y
\end{gather}
\end{definition}

Let $F_w=\{f\in Y^X\mid f\text{ satisfies Whatever 2}\}$.
\end{frame}

\end{document}

The above MWE generates the following output:

I have three problems with the above output:

I need the space above both Definitions to be the standard space between normal paragraphs, which is set to 10pt.
I need the space after Definition (Whatever 1) to be the standard space between normal paragraphs, which is set to 10pt.
I need the space after equation (1) to be the standard space between normal paragraphs, which is set at 10pt.

I have tried many things I have found on this site, to no avail. Any help will be much appreciated.

I wouldn't use setspace with beamer, it causes "funny" problems, like disappearing footnotes...

What's the use of \setlength\parindent{0pt} in a beamer document?

No need to load amsmath and amssymb, beamer will load it automatically

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you very much for your three comments. (1) I have deleted the package setspace from the MWE; but in my real document I am using \spacing{Xpt}, so how should I adjust line spacing in Beamer, then? (2) I have removed \setlength\parindent{0pt}, it was there because I was copy-pasting from an article. (3) I have now deleted these two packages from the preamble. Finally, any clue (even if small) on how to achieve what I ask in the question?

You could use a tcolorbox for the definition:
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}

\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Whatever 1}
Some random text.

Some more random text.
\begin{definition}[Whatever 1]
    A function $f:X\to Y$ if the moon is pink.
\end{definition}

Let $F_w=\{f\in Y^X\mid f\text{ satisfies Whatever 1}\}$.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Whatever2}
Some random text.

Some more random text.
\begin{definition}[Whatever 2]
    A function $f:X\to Y$ satisfies Whatever 2 if the next equation is satisfied:
\begin{gather}
    f(x)=y
\end{gather}
\end{definition}

Let $F_w=\{f\in Y^X\mid f\text{ satisfies Whatever 2}\}$.
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thank you very much for your great answer—it is almost what I am looking for. Would it be possible to not change the vertical space between Definition (Whatever 2) and the text that follows (i.e., A function $f:X\to Y$…)?

@EoDmnFOr3q You can change everything in a tcolorbox.

I don’t doubt it, but I wouldn’t know how…
